# what is the german equivalent of "skiffs"

Tags: english-to-german, standard-german

what is the german word of skiffs?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, which you did not give, it might be either "Ruderboot" or "Jolle".

A "Ruderboot" is a small vessel without sails, whereas a "Jolle" might also have a (small) "sail".

Answer (score 2):

The word "Das Skiff" also exists in German. It refers to a single person rowing boat, a so called "Einer".

https://www.dwds.de/wb/Skiff

Comment: Additionally, it's not commonly understood by an average German.

Comment: That's right, but the same may be true for "Einer" and "Jolle".

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I think the average German knows "Jolle" to be a vessel, while he might have no idea what "Skiff" and "Einer" are. That's just my feeling.

Comment: @Ludi Well, I didn't know the word Skiff existed in German either :-) But I still think it is worth noting that it does.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar certainly worth it!